# Eclipse: insert '}' to complete block

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code to draw a rectangle which works just fine:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.setPaint(new Color(128, 0, 0));
        Rectangle2D.Double s = new Rectangle2D.Double(20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0);
        g2.draw(s);
    }
```

after I replace it with this code

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.setPaint(new Color(128, 0, 0));
        Shape[] shapeList = new Shape[3];    
        shapeList[0] = new Rectangle2D.Double(20.0,20.0,40.0,70.0);  
        shapeList[1] = new Ellipse2D.Double(20.0,20.0,40.0,70.0);  
        int[] x = { 10, 50, 70 };  
        int[] y = { 20, 70, 20 };  
        shapeList[2] = new Polygon(x,y,3);  
         // now update the display 
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
            g2.draw(shapeList[i]);
            }
          
    }
```

I get a syntax error telling me that I have to insert "}" on this line

```
g2.draw(shapeList[i]);
```

I haven't figured out why yet, but I think I'm missing something somewhere.

This is my entire code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameDrawings extends JPanel {
    public FrameDrawings() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.setPaint(new Color(128, 0, 0));
        Rectangle2D.Double s = new Rectangle2D.Double(20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0);
            Shape[] shapeList = new Shape[3];    
            shapeList[0] = new Rectangle2D.Double(20.0,20.0,40.0,70.0);  
            shapeList[1] = new Ellipse2D.Double(20.0,20.0,40.0,70.0);  
            int[] x = { 10, 50, 70 };  
            int[] y = { 20, 70, 20 };  
            shapeList[2] = new Polygon(x,y,3);  
             // now update the display 
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
                g2.draw(shapeList[i]);
                }
              

    }
}
```

Comment: The code is correct, are you sure you've saved/rebuilt properly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.  I just put it in my eclipse and it only returned warnings. No errors.

Comment: I know, I verified it line by line for 5 minutes. I have no idea why it complains

Comment: This could possibly be an Eclipse related bug. Don't use Eclipse.

Comment: @jyoon I like Eclipse a lot, and java. I have no idea though how to solve that

Comment: Try out NetBeans or IntelliJ. You will like it. Alternatively you can create a new project and move the code over.

Comment: This is probably something where you've got a dodgy JDK or something.  Can you create a new project and print "hello world"?  If that works, then slowly add the code in from this app and see if/when it breaks.

Comment: @Alex I have no idea why it works with the first code, and with the second it complains.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I went Project --> Clean  and I still get the same error

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75759/discussion-on-question-by-bogdan-daniel-eclipse-insert-to-complete-block).